# Neo4j Dump and Restore

Tags: neo4j

Ubuntu 20.04 running multiple databases running with different version numbers in a project in Neo4j Desktop 1.2.7 and need to move them over to a newly installed machine with the latest version of Neo4j Desktop (not sure which version that is because on the SSD that's unplugged right now!).

Tried:

`bin/neo4j-admin dump --database="MYDATABASENAME" --to=/dumps/MYDATABASENAME-.dump"`

Which gives error "Database does not exist" error as I understand the default database is "neo4j" and that this somehow contains the other databases?  Makes no sense to me.

Tried:

`bin/neo4j-admin dump --database=neo4j --to=/dumps/DougiDatabases.dump"`

...Thinking that the neo4j database may contain all the other databases and that did dump. but the file was only 5Mb or so, where my databases are a number of Gb, so clearly not correct.

In system database I do `SHOW DATABASES` and it shows me the `neo4j` and `system` databases, but nothing else.

I've seen some mention of a dump button in the three dots by a database in Neo4j Desktop, but I don't have that (regardless of DB running or not).  I only have a clone option.

Previously I have copied the database files from the `/home/MYNAME/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases` folder and then updated the databases listed in the `/home/MYNAME/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/persist/databases.json`, but it seems that the folder structure in the latest version of Neo4j Desktop has a different structure, so I wasn't sure if I could still do this.  Not tried.

Driving me mad.  This should be so easy.

What do I do please?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.  For databases 3.x you need to use "graph.db" as the database name.  For databases 4.x you always use "neo4j" as the database name.

e.g.

`bin/neo4j-admin dump --database="graph.db" --to="/dumpsFolder/myDatabase.dump"`

`bin/neo4j-admin dump --database="neo4j" --to="/dumpsFolder/myDatabase.dump"`

You need to to into the admin area for each database, launch the terminal and execute these commands.  In the latest version of Neo4j Desktop you can then copy the dump files into the root of the project.  e.g.

`/home/USERNAME/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/projects/project-XXX`

Then click the ... next to the dump name in Neo4j Desktop and "create from dump file" or similar.  You select the database version, name it, set a password and continue.  The database will restore.